# find the shortest word in an array

Tags: javascript

id like to get the shortest word in the array.
this returns the first word which is "bil" even though "ei" is the shortest.
how can i define a word is shorter than the others?

```
const words= ['bil', 'plante', 'kaffe', 'bog', 'ei', 'planetarium'];

function getShortestWord() {
  for(let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    const strSplit = words[i].split('');
    let lengthOfWord = strSplit.length;

    if(strSplit[i].length < lengthOfWord) {
      lengthOfWord = strSplit[i].length
    }
    return lengthOfWord
   }
}
getShortestWord()
```

Comment: `lengthOfWord = strSplit.length` but then you check `strSplit[i].length < lengthOfWord` - `strSplit` is already the same thing and you shouldn't be getting `i` index from it.

Comment: Strings already have `.length`, so why the `split`? Tip: Sort by length, take first element.

Comment: Read your code out loud.... " I call getShortestWord. I loop over words. I split the first index by characters. I store the length into lengthOfWord. I than check it the current length of the index is less than lengthOfWord.....

Answer (score 3):

Sort array by their length.

```js
const words = ["bil", "plante", "kaffe", "bog", "ei", "planetarium"];
let ret = words.sort((x, y) => x.length - y.length);
console.log(ret[0]);
```

Comment: Way more iterations than actually is needed.

Comment: Bad from time complexity wise. O(nLogn).

Comment: @Abhishek how did you calculate time complexity for this? Please tell.

Comment: Inbuilt `sort` by default uses quick sort. And it's time complexity for it.

Answer (score 2):

```js
const wordsArray = [
  'bil', 
  'plante',
  'kaffe',
  'bog',
  'ei',
  'planetarium'
];

function shortestWordInArray(words){
  let result = "";
  words.forEach(
    word => {
      word.length < result.length ?
        result = word : null
    }
  )
  console.log(result)
  return result;
}

shortestWordInArray(wordsArray)
```

This would be my approach, iterate the items and store the lengthier.

Comment: The OP wants to get the shortest word and not the longest word!

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix the return and split statement. You are using array, so don't need split statement.

```
function getShortestWord() {
  if(words == null || words.length < 1) { 
    return words; // handling empty array
  }

  let minLengthWord = words[0];
  for(let i = 1; i < words.length; i++) {
    if(words[i].length < minLengthWord.length) {
       minLengthWord = words[i];
    }
   }
   return lengthOfWord
   
}
```

Note: the `return` statement is outside the `for` loop. As we need to find shortest word, which we will know only when we traverse whole array.

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually track and then return the word that you determine to be shortest.  Also, string.length will directly give you the length.  Note that I'm trying to stick as close to your concept as possible, for your learning purposes.  :)

```
const words= ['bil', 'plante', 'kaffe', 'bog', 'ei', 'planetarium'];

function getShortestWord() {
    let shortest = 0;
    for(let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {

        if(words[i].length < words[shortest].length) {
            shortest = i
        }
    }
    return words[shortest]
}

let shortest = getShortestWord()
console.log("Shortest = " + shortest)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just loop over the array storing the first element as the current shortest word to compare with, if another string has a shorter length then make it the current shortest word else just continue looping and check, finally return that word as it is the shortest word in that array

```js
const words = ['bil', 'plante', 'kaffe', 'bog', 'ei', 'planetarium'];

function getShortestWord(w) {
  let shortestWord = w[0];
  for(let i = 1;i < w.length; i++) {
    // it's just short circuit condition
    shortestWord.length > w[i].length && (shortestWord = w[i]);
  }
  return shortestWord;
}

console.log(getShortestWord(words));
```

Answer (score 0):

Find shortest words in array.

**Code:**

```
const words = [
"cat",
"dog",
"bird",
"elephant",
"lion",
"tiger",
"zebra",
"monkey",
"ox",
"b",
"a",
"giraffe",
"antelop",
];

function findShortestWords(words) {
let wordWithShortestLength = words.reduce((acc, current) => {
    if (current.length < acc.length) {
    return current;
    } else {
    return acc;
    }
}, words[0]);

let wordsWithShortestLength = words.filter((m)=>{
    return m.length == wordWithShortestLength.length
})
return wordsWithShortestLength
}

var shortest = findShortestWords(words);
console.log(shortest);
```

**Output:**

```
[ 'b', 'a' ]
```